# Laravel 5.1 hash check always returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, bcrypt, laravel-authorization

I'm new to laravel. Please help me.

this is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    /*
     *  mass assignable attributes
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'email',
        'uuid',
        'pwd_expired',
        'two_factor_auth_required',
        'is_editable',
        'version',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'pwd_hash',
        'merchant_id'
    ];
}
```

and Here is my authentication function .

```
public function authenticateUser(Request $data){

        // checking if there any user for given email
        if( $this->IsEmailUnique($data ->email)){
            return $this->setHeaders([
                'status' => 'fail',
                'msg' => 'No user recorded with given email address',
            ], 404 );
        }
        // if there is a user relevant to given email address
        else{

            // getting user relevant to given email
            $user = $this -> getSingleUserByEmail($data->email);

            // checking for password matching
            if( Hash::check($data -> password, $user -> pwd_hash)){

                return $this->setHeaders([
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'msg' => 'User successfully authenticated',
                    'user' => $user,
                    'merchant' => Merchant::where('merchant_id', $user -> merchant_id)->get()
                ], 200 );
            }
            // if authentication failed
            else{
                return $this->setHeaders([
                    'status' => 'fail',
                    'msg' => 'Invalid password for given username',
                ], 403 );
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm using my own user model. My password field in users column is more than 60 characters.everything works fine up to Hash::check. I've tested with var_dumps. But "Hash::check($data -> password, $user -> pwd_hash)" always returns false. please help me.

Also I'm writing all login in my UserController. I just need functionality.

Comment: Show the code how you are saving the password in the DB?

Comment: Using eloquent model. " $user -> pwd_hash = bcrypt($data -> password);" and "$user -> save();"